# How to use FormsAppCompatActivity outside of android project

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In Android project I have changed my Activity to  `FormsAppCompatActivity public class MainActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity`

However while i had Activity I was able to use it across the whole solution now i cant as its in different assembly as the `class is protected`. Can you please help me how to `use FormsAppCompatActivity  class in my Xamarin Forms project` i have been searching all over but i cant find anything.

```
    protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {

                Instance = this;

                // Changing to App's theme since we are OnCreate and we are ready to 
                // "hide" the splash
                base.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.ActionBar);
                base.SetTheme(Resource.Style.AppTheme);

                FormsAppCompatActivity.ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
                FormsAppCompatActivity.TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
               }
I am trying to achive lock screen and be able to manipulate wit my side buttons 

 public class LockScreenActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

           //Remove title bar

          Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
            Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DimBehind, WindowManagerFlags.DimBehind);
           Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen, WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
          Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn, WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);

           // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Drawable.lockScreenLayout);

          Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.backButton);
           button.Text = "JÍT ZPĚT";

           button.Click += delegate
           {
               base.OnBackPressed();
         };
      }
        public override bool OnKeyDown([GeneratedEnum] Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
        {
           if (keyCode == Keycode.VolumeDown)
           {
               LangUpArticlePlayer.GoOneSentenceBack(LangUpListenedArticle.GetTrackId());
               return true;
           }

            if (keyCode == Keycode.VolumeUp)
           {
               LangUpArticlePlayer.PlayPause();
               return true;
           }
            else
          {
           return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
         }
  }
   }
```

and in my shared project i have this to activate the lock

```
  protected void LockScreen(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var second = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(LockScreenActivity));
            second.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(second);

        }
```

Comment: Why you want to use FormsAppCompatActivity  class in the Xamarin Forms project? What you want to achieve?

Comment: I need to have a lock screen for my application and be able to use side buttons. And if i leave my class in my android project is not accessible and FormsAppCompatActivity is not accessible outside of android. SO now i am not really sure what to do

Comment: Can you please share us some code about using FormsAppCompatActivity? Try to add reference: using `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;` when you use 
FormsAppCompatActivity in shared project.

Comment: I have tried that, however i am not able to add its as i am getting an error that the using directive is unnecessary. I will update my question in a second

Comment: So if i have this class outside of android i cant access FormsAppCompatActivity and if i have this class in droid i cant access the class in the shared project even when i am using references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Android code directly in shared project. In this scenario, you need to use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction#resolve-the-platform-implementations):

First define a interface in Shared project:

```
public interface ILockScreenService {
    void lockScreen();
}
```

Implementation in .Android project:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(LockScreenAndroid))]
namespace App276.Droid
{
    public class LockScreenAndroid : ILockScreenService
    {
        public void lockScreen()
        {
            var second = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(LockScreenActivity));
            second.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(second);
        }
    }
}
```

Call it in Shared project:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ILockScreenService service = DependencyService.Get<ILockScreenService>();
    service.lockScreen();
}
```

**Update**:

Remember to set **Theme = "@style/MainTheme"**:

```
[Activity(Label = "LockScreenActivity", Theme = "@style/MainTheme")]
public class LockScreenActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you i will try it later on and update you.

Comment: in my droid i need to have it like this LockScreenActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity if i use what you suggested then i am not able to set content view

Comment: Because if i dont use FormsAppCompatActivity i cant use anzthing from android

Comment: ok i have done this public class LockScreenActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity, ILockService

Comment: however i am getting an error here Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(second); Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: 'Unable to find explicit activity class {com.avat.droid.prod/crc647e54cf869bf9703c.LockScreenActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?'

Comment: @TomashVovran I uploaded a sample project [here](https://github.com/XfHua/Android-DependencyService) and please check it.

Comment: hi, thank you. However i am still getting the same exception

Comment: You get exception from my sample project?

Comment: no, yours is ok. However I am getting an exception on line  base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState); Android.Views.InflateException: 'Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>'

Comment: I guess you missed the theme tag.

Comment: thnak you it wiorked,